# Transposition on an arbitrary permutation of Symmetric group may coalesce disjoint cycles?

Tags: symmetric-groups

Say, an arbitrary permutation
in $S_7$ as:  $$\sigma =
\begin{pmatrix} 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
   \\3 2 5 7 6 1 4 \end{pmatrix} \implies (1356)(47)$$
Here, $\sigma^{-1}(3) = 1,\sigma^{-1}(4) = 7, \sigma(3) = 5, \sigma(4) = 7$.

To this we applied a transposition (swap among two elements) $\tau= (3,4)$.
This lead us to get:
$$\tau\sigma =\begin{pmatrix} 1 2 4 3 5 6 7 \\3 2 5 7 6 1 4\end{pmatrix} \implies (1374561)$$

But, the two disjoint cycles got merged.

Is it not wrong to affect the underlying structure?

Comment: What does "Is it not wrong to affect the underlying structure?" mean? Are you asking if it's really true that multiplying a permutation by a transposition changes its cycle type? Because yes, it does, almost always, and I really don't see a reason one might expect otherwise.

Comment: @runway44 Yes, am referring to change in the cycle type. In graph theory, what is the term used ( for operation) to show such change in graph structure?